# mysql resultset is very slow in php output

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query with 4000 rows in a resultset. If i execute this query in a query browser like Heidisql i get all 4000 lines in 0.5 seconds. If i make a `print_r($result);`  to view inside my Internet Browser, i get all datas in 30 seconds. That is a big difference!
I have tried with mysqli and PDO it is the same problem.
It is a simple query from twotable (with a left join) with 18 columns.
I have a where in my query and all criterias are indexed (2 index!)
I have a mysql 5.1 with a php 5.3

Here the code:

```
$db_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$db_handle->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT, false);
$time_start = microtime(true);

$sqlCFf = "
SELECT ....
";
$result_set = $db_handle->query($sqlCFf);

$result = $result_set -> fetchAll();
print_r ($result);

$time_end = microtime(true);

$time_res = $time_end - $time_start;
```

Here the result from EXPLAIN:

```
1   SIMPLE  f   range   center  center  20      51000   Using index condition; Using where; Using MRR
1   SIMPLE  g   ref compte  compte  62  func    1   Using where
```

if somebody has an idea to figure out more fast the output in PHP?

THX in advance

Comment: first thing first - run `explain select` of your query and share the result into the question.

Comment: how do you get your `$result` ? are there any `text` or `blob` columns in your result? are the DB and the PHP code on the same machine?... if it is the same query in HeidiSQL and when called from PHP, it is an issue of either the transport between mySQL and PHP or between the webserver and your browser or the handling of the data inside the PHP code

Comment: when you say `print_r($result);`, do you put that code inside a loop? And the loop ends in 30 seconds?

Comment: Please add some code

Comment: i have modified my question

Comment: try to put `$time_end = microtime(true);` before `print_r ($result);`, then tell me the result.

Comment: @user26409021 i get this: 0.49998712539673 seconds

Comment: @achillix So it's much faster right ?

Comment: @user26409021 yes, but after $time_end i wait 30 seconde for the print_r result in my browser.

Answer (score 0):

Using EXPLAIN

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM tablename
```

> Understanding EXPLAIN’s Output

```
          id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: categories
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4
        Extra: 
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, printing result in any programming language will consume a lot of resource/time..

From your code:

```
$result = $result_set -> fetchAll();
print_r ($result);
//you try to record the end time after printing then it will took longer and not a reliable approach
$time_end = microtime(true);
```

Try to re-arrange you code like this:

```
$result = $result_set -> fetchAll();

//put it here, then it will record the end time before printing, which is the right way to benchmark
$time_end = microtime(true);
print_r ($result);
```

Comment: i get this: 0.49998712539673 seconds, but after 30 seconds i get all datas via print_r. It is very long.

Comment: Let's try different approach.. Instead of using `print_r()`, try to pass the result into the browser and use JS to print using `console.log()`. See the difference.

Comment: sorry for the time, never worked with console.log, what is really cool. So i put the console.log after my while and he does it in 5 seconds! That is very good. How can i get this performance into my output?

Comment: What do you mean into my output?? I don't get it.. I believe you want to show the output to your user, which is on HTML.

Comment: sorry, for my output. The page has generated more faster in the console of the firefox debugger. And i want to have the same speed 'for my output' :-)